# HtAccess Rewrite works with [R] but fails with [L]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I am trying to make: sub.example.com/page rewrite to www.example.com/sub/page

I have this code which does work (note last character):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [R]
```

And this code that does not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [L]
```

I want the url to remain as the user typed it in, but this seems to produce a 500 error.  I've enabled logging to try to assist, but it doesn't provide any clues.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last Rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [P]
```

If you list your directory structure to show how `sub.example.com` and `www.example.com` are related, this may also be possible via a rewrite vs the more expensive (slower) proxy solution above.

Comment: You should probably mention that this requires the use of mod_proxy and does incur some performance penalty. It's not a plain rewrite.

Comment: This seems to have done exactly what I requested - THANK YOU!